# XSLT3 and Xpath2: Best way to identify greatest element below a threshold in sorted sequence?

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0

I'm Saxon 9.5EE implementation of XSLT3 with Xpath2 and looking for the fastest way to identify the greatest element in a sorted sequence $seq less than some given value $value.

As far as I know, there is nothing equivalent to "preceding::sibling" for sequences. This means that Xpath is less agile when traversing sequences than it is when traversing an XML tree.

That is to say, you cannot say $seq[. gt $value][1]/preceding-sibling:item[1] because the "/" is only defined for nodes and "preceding-sibling" would not reference the sequence but rather the XML tree whence the nodes in question came.

Anyway...

I have found two methods of doing this, but they seem needlessly complex.

One method is:

```
$seq[($seq!(if(. gt $value) then position() else ()))[1] - 1]
```

Another method is

```
<xsl:iterate select="$seq">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
<xsl:if test=". gt $trial">
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:sequence select="$seq[$pos - 1]"/>
    <xsl:break/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:iterate>
```

Is there a better way?

Incidentally, testing these two options gave interesting results. If I was only looking for the *position* of the item in question, then they ended up being practically identical in performance.

However, if I am actually interested in the value itself, the  option crushes the other... presumably because the sequence is already primed in memory owing to the iteration command.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$seq[. lt $value][last()]
```

Comment: On the surface, that has the disadvantage that it takes no account of knowledge that the sequence is sorted; if the desired item is near the beginning, the whole sequence will be scanned.

Comment: I tested this algorithm, and the results appear to depend greatly on XSL-implementation (i.e., how the underlying XSL processor works). WIth no byte-code generation, this method appears just as good as the iterate-break algorithm in Saxon implementation. With byte-code generation, this algorithm appears worse by between a factor of 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive function is the most elegant solution:

```
function f ($seq, $value, $bestSoFar) {
   if (head($seq) > $value)
   then $bestSoFar
   else f(tail($seq), $value, head($seq))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I had trouble getting this to work as an inline recursive expression in oXygen's Saxon EE, in particular it told me that $f had not been declared. However, that may have something to do with known problems of convincing Saxon 9.5.2 to use all the enhanced features. I'll try in oXygen's beta Saxon 9.5.1.1 release.

Comment: Inline functions are not easy to make recursive because a variable is not in-scope within its own initialiser. There's a technique called "Y-combinators" that gets around this, but it's not for the faint-hearted.

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation stores the sequences as array, the fastest way is to use binary search which is `O(log n)`, instead `O(n)` like the linear search of the other answers.

If your implementation can calculate subsequences in O(1) by keeping range references you can use:

```
 function f ($seq, $value, $best) { 
    if (count($seq) = 0) then $best
    else let $midi := (count($seq) + 1) idiv 2
    return if ($seq[$midi] <= $value) then f(subsequence($seq, $midi + 1), $value, $seq[$midi])  
    else f(subsequence($seq, 1, $midi - 1), $value, $best)
  }
```

Otherwise you can keep the subsequence as function parameters:

```
 function f ($seq, $first, $last, $value, $best) { 
    if ($last < $first) then $best
    else let $midi := $first + ($last - $first) idiv 2
    return if ($seq[$midi] <= $value) then f($seq, $midi + 1, $last, $value, $seq[$midi])  
    else f($seq, $first, $midi - 1, $value, $best)
  }
  function call-f($seq, $value) {
    f($seq, 1, count($seq), $value, ())
  }
```